# Оставить только строки в определенном теге

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++, теги

Есть многострочный текст вида:

```
произвольный текст
<тег>строка_1</тег>
произвольный текст
<тег>строка_2</тег>
...................
<тег>строка_N</тег>
произвольный текст
```

Количество строк не определено. Задача: в Notepad++ сделать замену таким образом, чтобы на выходе оставались только строки в теге:

```
<тег>строка_1</тег>
<тег>строка_2</тег>
...................
<тег>строка_N</тег>
```

Наиболее рабочим оказался вариант `[\s\S]*?(<тег>.*?</тег>)[\s\S]*?`, но он оставляет "хвост" в виде текста, который был после последней строки с тегом.

Спасибо и не стреляйте в пианиста...))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

**Найти**:       `^(?!<тег>.*</тег>$).*\R?`
**Заменить**: `<пусто>`

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!<тег>.*</тег>$)` - отрицательный блок просмотра вперёд, строка не должна начинаться с `<тег>` и заканчиваться `</тег>`
- `.*` - ноль и более любых символов, отличных от переноса строки, как можно больше (целая строка)
- `\R?` - опциональная любая последовательность переноса строки.

См. настройки и [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/AIwALh/1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, большое спасибо за быстрый и красивый ответ!
Я уже подходил к тому, что нужно действовать "от обратного", но... не подошел).
Еще раз - спасибо.

Comment: А если усложнить задачу и допустить, что в тегах не строка, а произвольный многострочный текст?

Comment: @OldSteamer Да, можно, используйте регулярное выражение `^(<тег>(?s:.*?)</тег>)$|^.*$\R?` для поиска и шаблон `$1` для замены.

Comment: To @Wiktor Stribiżew. Но как, Холмс?! Спасибо)).